# Wordpress search with document Processing/Scan

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-wordpress-pages

I have posts with documents as attachment which we saved it as post meta.
**Whenever user search with any keyword on site it should look into the document as well for that keyword**. If keyword found then we will show the post in search results.

The SearchWP indexing the document but content Field on edit screen is empty.

Please let me know if anyone knows it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into elasticpress.

Comment: but how can we enable the document content to get involve in search because i tried with multiple files PDF and doc but none is working

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to try using the [Elasticpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elasticpress/) plugin.

From the homepage:

Documents: Indexes text inside of popular file types, and adds those files types to search results.